# Realize router transitions for solely one component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following routes. I want only one route to be transitioned, namely `/about`. No other route shall have a routing transition. The component `About` shall be animated in from the bottom to top overlapping the previous component.

How can I ensure only the given route to be transitioned? Additionally the component `CartHolder` shall not be removed on route change - as you can see in the code below, I want it to be displayed on two different paths.

How can I realize such behavior? Is `react-router-transition` the way to go? - If so, how can I consider the conditions above?

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();

function App() {

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router history={history}>
                <ScrollToTop>
                    <Header/>
                    {projects ?
                        <div>
                            <Route path="/project/:name" component={() => <Project carts={projects}/>}/>
                            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                            <div className="hs">
                                <Route path={["/", "/project/:name"]} exact
                                       component={() => <CartHolder carts={projects}/>}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="hs-mobile">
                                <Route path="/" exact component={() => <CartHolderMobile carts={projects}/>}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        : <div className="black-overlay"/>}
                </ScrollToTop>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}
```